# How to capture only one transaction from multiple authorized transactions?

Tags: paypal, relational-database, payment

I am building a payment system where a user can make a payment against an `orderId`

I want to make sure that only one payment gets through (gets captured)

The payment flow is like this:

1- User clicks on Paypal button

2- a Transaction `PENDING_PAYMENT` gets created for the user with `orderId`

3- User pays in Paypal

4- Paypal sends webhook and marks the payment as `AUTHORIZED`

5- The system `CAPTURES` the payment

as you see, the user can open multiple Paypal pages and pay all of them at the same time, there's no way for me to prevent this, but I want to be able to `CAPTURE` only one of these payments. (so I can automatically refund the rest of the payments)

I really appreciate any help, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the PayPal transaction for approval, pass a unique `invoice_id` to PayPal that has never before been used for a successful payment on that PayPal account.  This could be your `orderId`, perhaps with some additional prefix added if desired.  (For instance if you had multiple storefronts on the same PayPal account that might use the same order numbers, a prefix of 3 letters and a dash indicating the store name is a typical choice)

By default, PayPal accounts prevent (block) any subsequent payments for an `invoice_id` that was previously used for a successful payment on that account -- precisely to prevent accidental payments for the same thing, as is your use case.

Comment: I asked my question in a general matter, let's say I'm using another payment method (like bitpay) which only has `CAPTURE`, how would I detemine if a payment is a duplicate?

Comment: Well actually you **didn't** ask your question in a general manner, but the general solution to the question you didn't ask is to add your own validation before capturing. That is, anytime you get a successful capture, mark that orderId as paid in your database. And before attempting any capture, check whether that mark was set.